# hash library moved , then how should i change my old code

Tags: hash, node.js, traversal

As hash library is moved  seperate. so how should i change this code 
to work.

```
 var Hash = require('traverse/hash'); 
 Hash({ a : 1, b : 2 }) 
 .map(function (v) { 
    return v + 1 
 }) 
 .update({ b : 30, c : 42 }) 
 .filter(function (v) { 
    return v % 2 == 0 
 }) 
 .tap(function () { 
    var anyC = this.some(function (value, key) { 
      return key == 'c' 
    }); // or just this.keys.some, but anyways 
    console.log(anyC ? "There's a C key this far." : "There's no C key this far." ); 
 }) 
 .items ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var Hash = require('hashish');